Problem converting android resource drawable to bitmap
I have an Android resource drawable that I want to use in a BitmapShader call to a paint object.
I keep getting problems in trying to convert this Android drawable to bitmap.
I have tried:
Drawable theBackground =   ContextCompat.getDrawable(FullscreenActivity.wkContextRef.get(),R.drawable.grid_background);
      Bitmap backDraw = ((BitmapDrawable)theBackground).getBitmap();

Then, it says that I can not convert GradientDrawable to BitmapDrawable!
I have also tried:
Bitmap bii = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(FullscreenActivity.wkContextRef.get().getResources(),R.drawable.grid_background);

Then, when I set the BitmapShader on the paint it says the Bitmap must be non-null.
This is how I define my paint object and how I set the shader on the paint object:
Paint pintura=new Paint();
    pintura.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

    pintura.setPathEffect(new ComposePathEffect(
            new CornerPathEffect(100f) , new DiscretePathEffect(15f,55f)
    ));

    pintura.setShader(new BitmapShader(bii,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

How can I use this resource drawable in the BitmapShader call?
I have tried converting the resource drawable to a bitmap by using BitmapFactory.decodeResource() AND
creating a Drawable with ContextCompat.getDrawable() and then converting that drawable to BitmapDrawable to use the method getBitmap().

The AndroidX Core artifact provides an extension function for this:
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.toBitmap

//...

val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap(width = 100, height = 100)

From Java, this can be called as:
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.DrawableKt;

//... 

DrawableKt.toBitmap(
  drawable, /* width= */ 100, /* height= */ 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)


Hello @KevinCoppock is this only used in Kotlin or can I use it in Java? What is the minimum API needed? thanks!

There aren't any min API requirements for the method. You can call it from the enclosing file from Java; I've updated the answer to include the Java invocation as well.

Hello @KevinCoppock I like your concise answer! I don't know what Java ever did to Android ecosystem for them to change exclusively to Kotlin. It seems like now they are trying to push aside Flutter in favor of Kotlin Multiplatform. I just don't like the syntax of Kotlin and its constructs really confuse me! I rather wing it with the old Java way. But, now I am more focusing on game development which Android is not the best at! Maybe in the future?

Ok so here is how I solved it!
Since I am exclusively using Java and refuse to use Kotlin ever! I just drew the Drawable on a canvas object. Then, I used the Bitmap backing the canvas object as a shader for my paint object. Here is the code that retrieves the drawable from the resources, creates the bitmap backing the canvas draw operations and sets the shader on the paint object. It looks really nice.
//get the resource drawable:
 Drawable biitty = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(FullscreenActivity.wkContextRef.get().getResources(),
           R.drawable.grid_background,null);

//create canvas and size of Bitmap backing canvas. Do note that you must get the view size that will host the Bitmap drawn by the canvas object! 

 int height = mainConstraintLayoutHeight;
   int width =  mainConstraintLayoutWidth;

    Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    biitty.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    biitty.draw(canvas);

//now, modify your paint object with some cool looking effects!


Paint pintura=new Paint();
    pintura.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

 pintura.setPathEffect(new ComposePathEffect(
            new CornerPathEffect(100f) , new DiscretePathEffect(15f,55f)
    ));

    pintura.setShader(new BitmapShader(mutableBitmap,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

Now, the paint object will use the drawable resource as a shader and draw nice effects with it!
